# Librería xmltooling java

Tags: java, genexus, seguridad, libreria, war

un escaneo de seguridad de mi aplicación creada con GeneXus arrojó una vulnerabilidad CVE-2019-9628 en la librería XMLTooling provista por Shibboleth Service Provider, que se arreglaría con la versión V3.0.4. El problema es que no encuentro un archivo .jar correspondiente a esa versión. Si bien el fuente original en C tiene todas las versiones, no así el wrapper de java que apenas llega hasta la 1.4.6 hasta donde pude ver. Alguien conoce una solución para este problema? Supongo que se puede crear a aprtir del código C pero no soy desarrollador C ni Java. Desde ya gracias por cualquier información que me puedan aportar.